# Anki deleted my deck... Any chance to restore?

Tags: backup, anki

I am using [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) both on my desktop and mobile.

I created a long deck on desktop by hand and ran sync. It asked me whether I want to download or upload, and I selected to download. I didn't think it would delete the existing deck just because it is absent on server, but it did just that.

Is it possible to restore it?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, Anki does automatic backups you can recover from

### Anki Mobile Backup Restoration

The mobile client does automatic backups of collections in the background, which you can restore by going to `Preferences` → `Backups` and select the backup you want to use.

> AnkiMobile will automatically create backups of your collection for you. The backups include all your cards and statistics, but do not include sounds or images, since they take up a lot of space.
>
> The backup is taken in the background when you return to your device’s home screen, or switch to another app. A backup will only happen if more than an hour has elapsed since the last time a backup was created. AnkiMobile will store the last 15 backups.
>
> To restore from a backup, open the Backups section in the preferences, and tap on the backup you wish to restore to.

From the [Anki manual](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/am-manual.html#backups), in the 'Backups' section.

### Anki Desktop

In my Anki directory, I have a `backups` entry with backups present:

[image: anki backups]

*(backup listing, not all entries shown)*

So check in `~/.local/share/Anki/<profilename>/backups`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is about Linux system, but in macOS, the backup directory is located in the following path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Anki2/Username/backups
```